# Mirror Firebase Cloud Storage Directory to a Dropbox Directory

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage, dropbox

I'm very new to using Firebase Cloud Storage. I'm currently using it to store data generated by some in-house tablet apps. We want users to be able to easily access this data in the form of Dropbox, however don't want to integrate the Dropbox API into our tablet applications as we're already using Firebase for all login management, etc and don't want users to have to login twice.

Is it possible to setup of a mirror between Firebase Cloud Storage and a Dropbox account such that any file added to Firebase Cloud Storage is immediately copied to the Dropbox directory?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use [cloud functions which are being triggered by cloud storage service](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/gcp-storage-events) (it will triggered on any uploading, updating, deleting files or folders) on your firebase project and then write your cloud functions in a way to use dropbox api and then make the same change in the dropbox directory structure.

Cost and performance wise I don't think it would an efficient thing to do, unless it is what really you want.